# PDF export with phantomjs-node: paperSize and vievportSize

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I have almost mastered the PDF export with PhantomJS. As long as the PDF should be 14.67 * 11.33 inches.

I am using the [node phantom package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) in order to create and render a local website to PDF from my NodeJS backend.

I set pageSize and viewportSize to 'Letter'.

I set the pageSize and viewportSize before and after I load a page.

I set the html, body to the exact dimensions. Literally nothing has any effect on the output size. On my Windows develop machine this seems to be fixed 14.67 * 11.33.

The content itself is at the correct size ('Letter, landscape' 11 * 8.5 inches) in the top left corner of the output.

I am close to using a 3rd party PDF tool and cut the away the rest of the document. But I am sure there is a smarter way of doing this.

Here is a bit of css:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    width: 11in;
    height: 8.5in;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.page {
    width: 11in;
    height: 8.5in;
    padding: 0.3in;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is some PhantomJS magic.

```
page.paperSize = {
    format: 'Letter',
    orientation: 'landscape'
};

page.viewportSize = { width: 1056, height: 816 };

page.open(url, function () {
    page.render('output.pdf');
});
```

And here is a screenshot of a PDF generated from this. The black border being at the correct Letter, landscape format.

[image]

Comment: The code you've presented here would work in a plain PhantomJS script. It would work differently in a node.js bridge for PhantomJS. Have you checked the documentation? Are you sure you're using a node.js bridge and not PhantomJS directly?

Comment: That solved it... Thanks. The phantom bridge does indeed set the properties different. page.property('viewportSize', {width: 1056, height: 816})